# Why does zip change my lists?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I noticed a (to me) very strange behavior, I don't understand:
I got a list and an numpy array both with binary values and I want to check the true positives (both==1 at the same time).

```
import numpy as np
a = [0,0,1,1]
b = np.array([1,0,1,0])

for a,b in zip(a,b):
  if a==1 and b==1:
      print "cool"
print a,b
```

Now the craziness begins. a and b are not longer a list or a numpy array but an integer and numpy float? How on earth did that happen?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`zip` did not change your list. You lost the initial references to your lists when you assigned the name `a` and `b` to the loop variables in:

```
for a, b in zip(a,b):
#   ^  ^
```

A simple fix is to change those names to say, `i` and `j`:

```
for i, j in zip(a,b):
```

One thing to bear in mind when using Python is that names are bound to objects, and therefore can be *unbound* or even *rebound*. No name is for keeps. Once you change the object a name is referencing like you did, the name starts to reference the new object.

On another note, `for` loops assign the objects from the iterable to the name(s) provided, similar to a regular assignment, but with repetitions. So the values you get for `a` and `b` at the end of the `for` loop are those of the last assignment done in the last iteration.

Do bear these in mind.

Comment: thank you very much, I forget to choose different loop variables. I didn't know that an assignment takes place in a for loop. I always thought the loop just creates it's own namespace and throws the looping variables away when it has finished. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose `a` is a list, and you write `a = a[0]`. Now you'd expect `a` to be not a list, but the first value in the list.

Similarly, when you write `for a,b in zip(a,b)` you re-assign `a` and `b` to hold the first element in each iterable. Try:

```
for x,y in zip(a,b):
  if x==1 and y==1:
      print "cool"
print a,b
```